# How to duplicate dependent drop down list in other columns with the same list source in Google Sheet

Tags: validation, google-sheets, dropdown, google-sheets-formula

I have two drop-down list say C5 and D5. D5 is dependent on selection from C5. I have been able to achieve this dependency successfully. I will like to have the same drop-down list be duplicated across C6:C and D6:D keeping the same dependency and same list.

Please any help

Comment: Please choose one app, they will be done differently.  As is it is too broad a question as it is asking for two different answers.

Answer (score 1):

the best way to do so is to copy-paste it or drag it all the way down. google sheets lacks the ability to mass-assign ranges of data validation